# is there a way to shift the top of the screen down in full screen mode in iTerm2?

Tags: macbook-pro, iterm, fullscreen

I just got a new 14" macbook pro, which I love so much..  However, as soon as I launched iTerm2 and went into full screen mode, I said "uh oh" as I noticed my tabs were covered by the "notch."

Is there any known way to shift down the top of the screen in fullscreen mode of iTerm2 so that I can not be inconvenienced by this?

[image]